# What router does the MEAN stack with Angular 4 normally use?

Tags: angular

What router is recommended if you are doing a mean stack with Angular 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options: **Angular router (comes with angular core)** and **[UI-Router](https://ui-router.github.io/)** (Third party router).

Personally I prefer Angular router as it is provided by Angular and will have long term support for any bugs.

UI-Router has more functionality than Angular router and its been around for quite some time now. It uses state based routing which can be achieved in Angular router using child routing. So if you are using Angular router then you'll have to put some extra work to get UI-Router functionally.

I don't think that stack matters in your case. As you will be using http or web services to call server. The routing problem remains at client side only.